# Xamarin forms sql lite table add foreign key constraints

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I have my app creating tables using models where i want to add foreign key constraints.

Here is Base Table:

```
public class BaseTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is child table

```
public class ChildTable
{
    [ForeignKeyConstraint(BaseTable.ID, ID)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my App.xaml.cs i am creating db like so:

```
database.CreateTable<BaseTable>();
database.CreateTable<ChildTable>();
```

For this line:

```
[ForeignKeyConstraint(BaseTable.ID, ID)]
```

I am getting object ref is required which makes sense however i want to add the foreign key relationships in the model child table.

Thanks in advance for any advice on how i can accomplish this

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/

Comment: @Jason I was able to use that to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing SQLiteNetExtensions i was able to do following to solve my problem:

```
public class ChildTable
{
    [ForeignKey(typeof(BaseTable))]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then updated my base table like following:

```
public class BaseTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)] 
    public List<ChildTable> ChildTables { get; set; }
}
```